# I Extruded up with z and scaled down 8 times but have a square to deal with

Tags: modeling

[image]

You're looking at a leather seat from a dining chair. I modeled this chair seat by creating the very bottom loop of vertices then extruded them up and scaled down many times using the image planes as a guide. I was surprised it worked as well as it did but in the picture you can see what I ended up with at the top.
Maybe there's a better way to model this?
Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Do you want the center to be only one vertices?

Answer (score 3):

If you want the center to be just vertices (As shown in @Neil's answer), click alt+m while only selecting the square in the center.

But if you want the center to be a circle:

1. Select only the center square
2. Press Space bar (EDIT: Press `F3` instead as `Space bar` was for an outdated version of Blender)
3. Type in **sphere** and click the to sphere option.
4. mess with the values in the tool bar (Scroll to bottom of toolbar) to get your desired result.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your reference in the image you posted, I would approach this by modelling it a little differently. As the object is now, it has probably more geometry than is really needed:

1. With a new plane object,  <kbd>Tab</kbd> into *edit mode* and
           *subdivide* two or three times. <kbd>W</kbd>*>Subdivide*
2. Next, *extrude* along the *Z* axis to the height you want your
           object to be with <kbd>E</kbd>
3. Enable *proportional editing* with <kbd>O</kbd>, and select the
           centermost vertex and translate it up along the *Z* axis. Adjust the influence with the middle mouse wheel until you
           like how it looks.
4. Disable proportional edit with <kbd>O</kbd>, and select the bottom
       edge loop, then flatten it by scaling it to 0 on the *Z axis*  using<kbd>S</kbd>
       <kbd>Z</kbd> <kbd>0</kbd>
5. Add a slight crease to the bottom edge loop with
       <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>  (Optional)
6. Add a *subsurf modifier* and *shade smooth*.

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

If you want the center face to be only one vertex, simply select the face and press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd>>*Merge at center*.

Many people actually recommend keeping the face a square, since it works better with modifiers.